# Light with vertex/fragment shader. Using varying variables. (openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I was looking for a lot of this problem. I found this question [Passing data into different shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071290/passing-data-into-different-shaders) but this problem not mine. I get "The fragment shader uses varying "normal", but previous shader does not write to it." error message.

My vertey shader code:

```
#version 430

in layout(location=0) vec3 position;
in layout(location=1) vec3 normal;

out vec3 norm;

uniform mat4 transformation;

void main()
{   
    gl_Position = transformation * vec4(position, 1.0);
    norm = (transformation * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
}
```

And my fragment shader code:

```
#version 430

in vec3 normal; 
out vec4 colour;

vec3 lightPos = vec3(0,50,0); 
vec3 lightColor = vec3(0.5, 0, 0); 
vec3 materialColor = vec3(0, 1.0, 0);

void main() {
    float cosTheta = dot(-lightPos, normalize(normal));     
    vec3 temp = materialColor * lightColor * cosTheta;  
    colour = vec4(temp, 1.0); 
}
```

What is the main problem? I don't understand this message my vertex shader using the normal vector and it passing into fragment shader. I don't see difference between the linked code and mine. Please tell me some idea :\

Comment: Okay, I think this is my big mistake. Vertey shader output and fragment shader input it must have the same name.

Comment: they must have the same name, did this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different variable names for some reason you can specify a location to match in- and output variables.

For example, in your case:

.vert:

```
out layout(location = 7) vec3 norm;
```

.frag:

```
in layout(location = 7)vec3 normal;
```